# How i can get failed tests in after_all in behave?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-behave

I need to restart specific failed tests, and i wanna get failed tests in after_all for retry its.

I try to get tests from context, but i don't know what next to do.

Comment: Would you consider using pytest?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
failed_scenarios = []

def after_scenario(context: Context, scenario: Scenario) -> None:
    if scenario.status == "failed":
        failed_scenarios.append(context.scenario.name)

def after_all(context: Context) -> None:
    # Code to re-run the list of failed tests
```

Also, you can use other attributes of scenarios like tags, features, etc as per your use.

https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#behave.model.Scenario